# How to change individual bar colours of subplots in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, colors

I have the following code:

```
%initialize variables
titles = {'1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b', '7a', '7b', '8a', '8b', '9a', '9b', '10a', '10b', '11a', '11b', '12a', '12b', '13a', '13b', '14a'};
antibodies = {'Rel-A','p-Rel-A','IkBa','p-IkBa','A20'};
x_axis = {'PBS','GOX','TNF','L','M','H'};
colours = {'r','g','b','m','c'};
Y_axis = 'Fold TNF (OD)';

%plot graphs
h = figure('name','Cytoplasm,Averaged,1h');
for i=1:5,
    subplot(5,1,i)
    barwitherr(std_error{2}(i,1:6),averaged_data{2}(i,1:6),'BarWidth',0.7) %note that barwitherr is a downloadable function 
    set(get(gca,'YLabel'), 'String', Y_axis)
    set(gca, 'XTick', 1:6, 'XTickLabel', x_axis,'fontsize',18);  
    title(antibodies(i))

end
h=subplot(5,1,1);
set(h,'ylim',[0,15]);

h=subplot(5,1,3);
set(h,'ylim',[0,4]);

h=subplot(5,1,4);
set(h,'ylim',[0,4]);

h=subplot(5,1,5);
set(h,'ylim',[0,4]);
```

This generates my graphs nicely except I want to change the colours of the individual bars of the individual subplots. i.e. how would you change the first bar of the first subplot green but leave the rest blue?

Cheers

Comment: Not sure if it works the same way for `barwitherr()` but check out the documentation for [hist](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/hist.html). Specifically the point: "Change Histogram Color Properties". And if you can use it just use an if-case to change only those graphs you want.

Comment: No the FaceColor property doesn't exist with this graph (according to the error message anyway)

Comment: if you enter `,'r'` at the end of the `barwitherr()` does it then plot in red? If so you could enter an if-case which checks if it is the wanted graph and if so use a modified "plot". Not a nice solution but that should work

Comment: Unfortunately no, that hasn't worked - the error message: 'Incorrect number of inputs for property-value pairs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you use [this function](http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30639-bar-chart-with-error-bars/content/barwitherr.m).

If yes, then you can modify the code of barwitherr.m to change the colors.

1. To change the color of the bars to green after line 114 write

   ```
   set(handles.bar,'FaceColor','g')
   ```
2. To change the color of the ticks to red

   ```
   % replace line 126 with
   h = errorbar(mean(x,1), values(xOrder,col), lowerErrors(xOrder,col), upperErrors(xOrder, col), '.r');
   hc = get(h, 'Children');
   set(hc(2),'color','r')
   hErrorbar(col) = h;

   % after line 131 include
   set(hErrorbar,'color','y')
   hc = get(hErrorbar, 'Children');
   set(hc(2),'color','r')
   ```
3. Modify your for loop, where for the first plot you use modified barwitherr.m, and for the other ones you use the original one.
4. See [Jonathan's answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/20860-how-to-use-colormap-for-different-bars) to see how to change the color of the individual bars. If you replace there "colors = [0 1 0; 0 0 1; 0 0 1];"
   and add this modification to point 1 above, you will get what you want.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think a solution would be to use

```
[nelements , centers] = hist(Ydata,XData);
```

to get the bin counts of your data of interest, and then apply some threshold to your data so that only the data below the threshold is green and the rest is blue.

For instance:

```
CentersBelowTreshold = centers(centers < MinCutoffValue);
ElementsBelowTreshold = nelements(centers < MinCutoffValue);

CentersAboveTreshold = centers(centers > MinCutoffValue);
ElementsAboveTreshold = centers(centers > MinCutoffValue;
```

And then plot the bar graphs. I guess you can modify the source code of barwitherr since it basically plots bars with an additionnal input argument.

```
bar(CentersBelowTreshold,ElementsBelowTreshold,'g')

hold on

bar(CentersAboveTreshold,ElementsAboveTreshold,'b')
hold off.
```

Comment: Unless someone have an idea how to ungroup `hggroup` objects. It seems unlikely that this would not be possible.

Comment: By "ungroup hggroup object" do you mean like getting the objects' children and modify them separately?

Comment: Kind of, I am not sure if it is possible, but it seems unlikely that it should not be. The advantage is that the plot then can be modified after creation. This can be useful when writing reports and the figure does not look exactly as you want. Anyway +1 for your solution.